# Error : standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-20.04

When I use docker container I got the following error：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c0XV.png)

My computer is a 64-bit x64 operating system.docker version information 20.10.12.Ubuntu version is 20.03.

The docker log for running the command is as follows:

```
time="2022-01-03T10:50:26.312973100+08:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/b1cbf20dd5864e91c0d3ebe0522cb0e589babf5a30bc88caa3b23dea52de8e14 pid=853
time="2022-01-03T10:50:27.431678700+08:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=b1cbf20dd5864e91c0d3ebe0522cb0e589babf5a30bc88caa3b23dea52de8e14 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
time="2022-01-03T10:50:27.432538200+08:00" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=b1cbf20dd5864e91c0d3ebe0522cb0e589babf5a30bc88caa3b23dea52de8e14
time="2022-01-03T10:50:27.434013300+08:00" level=error msg="copy shim log" error="read /proc/self/fd/14: file already closed"
```

This is my run.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
HASH=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 4 | head -n 1)
GPU=$1
name=${USER}_pymarl_GPU_${GPU}_${HASH}

echo "Launching container named '${name}' on GPU '${GPU}'"
# Launches a docker container using our image, and runs the provided command

if hash nvidia-docker 2>/dev/null; then
  cmd=nvidia-docker
else
  cmd=docker
fi

NV_GPU="$GPU" ${cmd} run \
    --name $name \
    --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
    -v `pwd`:/pymarl \
    -t pymarl:1.0 \
    ${@:2}
```

THis is my docker image

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.2-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu16.04
MAINTAINER Tabish Rashid

# CUDA includes
ENV CUDA_PATH /usr/local/cuda
ENV CUDA_INCLUDE_PATH /usr/local/cuda/include
ENV CUDA_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib64

# Ubuntu Packages
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install software-properties-common -y && \
    add-apt-repository -y multiverse && apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y apt-utils nano vim man build-essential wget sudo && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install curl and other dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl libssl-dev openssl libopenblas-dev \
    libhdf5-dev hdf5-helpers hdf5-tools libhdf5-serial-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler git
RUN curl -sk https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/distro/master/install-deps | bash && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install python3 pip3
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade "pip < 21.0"

# Python packages we use (or used at one point...)
RUN pip3 install numpy scipy pyyaml matplotlib
RUN pip3 install imageio
RUN pip3 install tensorboard-logger
RUN pip3 install pygame

RUN mkdir /install
WORKDIR /install

RUN pip3 install jsonpickle==0.9.6
# install Sacred (from OxWhirl fork)
# RUN pip3 install setuptools
RUN pip3 install --upgrade -vv setuptools
RUN git clone https://github.com/oxwhirl/sacred.git /install/sacred && cd /install/sacred && python3 setup.py install

#### -------------------------------------------------------------------
#### install pytorch
#### -------------------------------------------------------------------
RUN pip3 install torch
RUN pip3 install torchvision snakeviz pytest probscale

## -- SMAC
RUN pip3 install git+https://github.com/oxwhirl/smac.git
ENV SC2PATH /pymarl/3rdparty/StarCraftII

WORKDIR /pymarl
```

Please help!!!!I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: "exec format error" means you're trying to run an executable compiled for the wrong OS or CPU. You're the person best positioned to inspect the binaries you're running.

Comment: Also, when you cut down the error to only give us the message from the failure itself but no surrounding context, you prevent us from knowing _which_ `RUN` command failed this way. We need more details of your hardware (yes, 64-bit, but 64-bit ARM, and of which endian? Or 64-bit PPC? 64-bit x86?) , and we need enough logs to identify the specific `RUN` that failed.

Comment: my computer is 64-bit x64.About logs，Which log should I look for

Comment: @Charles Duffy
my computer is 64-bit x64. About logs，Which log should I look for

Comment: @Charles Duffy   I am using WSL2

Comment: @Charles Duffy   I put the log in the main content

Comment: Not the specific log I was looking for, unfortunately. What we're looking for should be logged by the Docker _client_, not the daemon, in the same output as the error message itself.

Comment: @Charles Duffy  Sorry,I have been searching online for a long time， I didn’t find where to find the docker client logs. Can you provide more information, such as which file is the docker client logs? This problem has bothered me for a long time

Comment: Should be on the command line output, the same place you got the `standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error` message.

Comment: @Charles Duffy yes. The message is on the command line output

Comment: Right. I'm asking for the rest of the command line output, so we can see which RUN failed.

Comment: @Charles Duffy  Only this one error message.I posted the picture of command line out to the main content, you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around `$GPU` in your command (I'd include the fixed command here, but I can't copy/paste from a screenshot). It doesn't appear to be set, and without quotes, you're missing the python3 command that your container should be running (instead it's setting the gpu variable to python3 in your script).

Without the python3 command, it's trying to execute the python script, and it is likely missing the `#!` on the first line that would tell the kernel how to execute the script (this can also happen if the script isn't saved as utf-8 with Linux linefeeds).

Comment: I tried your suggestion, enter the command: `bash run.sh '$GPU' python3 src/main.py --config=qmix --env-config=sc2 with env_args.map_name=2s3z`,But another error appeared:`docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (jindingquan_pymarl_GPU_$GPU_4Rt7), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed.`I don't konw how to fix it.

Comment: This another error i don't know how to fix it

Comment: Do i need to remove this symbol $